# Internal Drive errors on specific drives; others are OK

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid

I'm running **Windows 8.1**

All my drives are formatted **NTFS**

I have several internal disk drives on my desktop. My **C:** (boot drive) is fine. But on my **D:** and **E:** drives (3 2TB Seagate drives in RAID 5 config) when I right click to create a folder I get this message:

**File Too Large. The file '<%1 NULL:NameDest>' is too large for the destination file system.**

I also get a **" " file is too large for destination folder** whenever I try to copy any file, no matter how small the file is.

I have run sfc.exe /scannow at command prompt and I get this result:

*... Verification 100% complete. Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.*

I've also run CHKDSK and get this:

*... 4596 data files processed. CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal... A disk read error occurredc000000d Insufficient disk space to fix the Usn Journal $J data stream.*

This issue is only happening on these two drives, and not any of the several other drives I have.

I have also discovered that when I right click > properties > tools and attempt to error check, I get this:

**There was a problem scanning this drive. Windows was unable to scan the drive**

PLEASE NOTE: I ran a SeaTools utility from the manufacturer and these Seagate drives passed the test. So I believe it's a Windows file system issue, and not a hardware issue, but really just don't know what the hell is going on.

Please help. Thx.

Comment: I have an identical problem to you except mine is an external 3TB USB drive